# Controls resizing issue

Tags: c#, .net, resize

(using c# .net and devex controls.)

I have dockable panel with a devex grid within a form.
this form is being derived by many other forms as base form.

Now if i try resizing the dockable panel with the grid in the derived form the size happens and the effect is seen when the application is run until we open the design file anymore.

Now when i again open the designer file in the application i c tht the size of the panel with grid is back to normal, basically am unable to handle the sizing in the derived form.

I want to do resizing in derived form as the size changes from form to form.

Can some one let me know wht would be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you considered using user controls and aggregation for your reuse instead of inheritance? I find that user controls work much better for what you are describing.

2) Use the anchors on the grid to anchor it to the left and right - it will resize in a smart way.

3) if you must resize the grid in descendant forms you can change the scope to be protected (Look for modifiers on the property grid.)

Comment: 1) This is an already developed applicatrion, now its s bug for me to fix, its not possible for me to change this to an user control at this stage

Comment: 2) I want to gesize the grid in height wise on certaion conditions, so anchors may not help me

Comment: 3) i have kept the modifiers as PUBLIC. but still no effect.

Comment: If you set the modifier on the grid in the base class to protected or public you should be able to resize it in the designer on the descendant. This is bad practice IMO - but it is possible.

Comment: There are anchors for top and bottom also.